# How to get rid of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a Vue.js app and there is a button that has vector icon in the middle. I want to make blink when click that button.

The code looks as following:

```
up (event) {
  event.currentTarget.style.background = 'blue'
  setTimeout(() => {
    event.currentTarget.style.background = '#fcfcfc'
  }, 100)
},
```

The issue is when I click button it paints in blue, but it doesn't paint back using setTimeout.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Objects in JS are passed using reference. My assumption is, event.currentTarget is being updated by some code. Thats causing issue. Better solution would be using CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DOM events propagate up the tree. So initially they fire on the element you'd expect (e.g. a button that was clicked) and then the same event will fire for all the ancestors of that element, one by one, gradually walking up the tree. The same `event` object is used for all of these events and some of the properties do change as it propagates up.

`event.target` is the element on which the original event occurred.

As an event propagates up the DOM tree, `event.currentTarget` reflects the current element in the propagation. So it starts off the same as `target` and gradually works its way up to the top of the DOM tree. Inside the function it will initially be the element that you registered the listener on. By the time the timer fires it will have walked up to the top of the tree.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

The solution would be to grab a reference to the element when you first encounter it:

```js
up (event) {
  const el = event.currentTarget
  el.style.background = 'blue'

  setTimeout(() => {
    el.style.background = '#fcfcfc'
  }, 100)
},
```